# How to force all the visitors to redirect to one page first then can continue to the other page

Tags: php, web

I have a member area page example `http://mywebsite.com/private/members.php`

and there is a gallery page which I place the link on the `members.php` which is `http://mywebsite.com/private/premium.php`

what I want to make is that when they already logged in if they visit the first time either they go directly to `http://mywebsite.com/private/premium.php` or clicked the `premium.php` from members.php page they will be redirect to this page first example `http://mywebsite.com/private/announcement.php` then they can click on the link to continue after they read my announcement first

I know this will be so annoying and complicate (maybe) but I just want them to see my announcement first before get to the premium.php page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a javascript (jquery for instance) popup with overlay on your /premium.php on load. I reckon would be a better way. Alternatevely you can send them to announcment page from /premium.php using header. 
On announcement page when they click next set a session variable. (Put next button in a form).
On premium page check for that session variable. If it's not set - header redirects them to announcement page, otherwise they stay on /premium.php
Still think simple modular poup would be better way to go about your announcement thingy.

Comment: your idea is very great for popup overlay and they can close it afterwards if they wish to.

any suggestion which or where to start sorry for being noob but I'm trying my best to learn

Comment: There are tons of plugins for modal windows using jquery or other libraries. Or you can create one yourself. This is just one tutorial: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial, you can find more. You can also use cookie plugin so users would not get popup every time they go that page http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 1):

if you have a login history table, you can check the `update_dt` on your last announcement and compare it to the `login_dt` of a users last login. If they have not logged in since the last announcement, you can direct them to your page.

Comment: I only have session in my database where should I look for those two?

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to see your announcement every time after a certain time-period, you would go set a cookie for some time (say 10 days) and see if it's there (if not, it's expired and you show your announcement again).

If you want them to see it the first time they click it after they registered on your site, I would add a Database-table with a `tinint` which is `0` if they didn't and is changed to `1` if they did.

---

In the case your described, I wouldn't use an other site (your `announcement.php`) but check it they read your announcement on the `premium.php`-site. If they did (the row-value is set to `1`), they see the site.

If not (the row-value is `0`), they see your announcement and you set the mentioned `tinyint` in your Database to `1`. After they saw it they can click on a link (which will redirect them to the `premium.php`-site, so basically reload the page) and then check again if the row-value is `1` (which will be the case). So they only see your announcement once.

Comment: the thing is that in the premium.php have many link inside of it

what I'm afraid of is that if they click on each link they will be redirect back again to the announcement page

but if I can find the way to redirect just the first time they visit the site doesn't matter on the premium.php direct or from members.php through the link to premium.php

basically they visiting my site just to go to premium.php but some of people bookmarked the premium.php so now they not going to members.php anymore

so I want them to see this before continue to see the gallery

Comment: Very confusing what you wrote. I'll try to answer it: If you want the user to be redirected to another site on a certain condition, you're going to need to check if he had already been redirected every time the site is loaded. If you do this before any content is printed out, the user won't see anything of your site.

Comment: Yes you got it right

I will try to explain it again in a clearly way as I could

My visitors they visit my site for watching Live TV let say.

And the main site is http://mywebsite.com then they will login after they logged in they will be redirect to http://mywebsite.com/private/members.php which is a members only area

but inside the member only area they have a premium channels which is premium.php

So before they can go to see premium.php I want them to read my announcement first I was thinking I may just place another page announcement.php and that we be it.

but I look at my

Comment: But I look at my google analytic report that they are half of people who bookmarked the premium.php which means they are going direct without visit the members.php first

So in this case if I can get all of the visitors either through members.php or direct visitors to visit the announcement.php first before continue to premium.php

Comment: Thanks I will try figure out what to do with the database so that I can implement by that

Answer (score 1):

I would have probably create a bridge table to tie the announcement and users together.  This table would store the primary key for the user table, the primary key from the announcement table, and a either a boolean field to indicate that the user has seen the announcement, or a date/time field to show when they read the announcement. (or both if you want)

When the users hit your premium page, you can check to see if the user has read the announcement by querying this table.  If the announcement has not been read, it will be a simple header redirect to take them to the correct page.

Comment: very good idea thanks will see what can I get into it

kinda new to this kind of stuff but trying my best to learn.

Comment: just make sure you make the insert into this table when they read the announcement or they will be redirected there every time. :)